# Map over data returned from aws-sdk on React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify for an application but it lacks the ability to admin users so I am using the aws-sdk in the short term until they add the feature.

I have been able to get data returned from a promise using the following code:

```
const ListUsers = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = () => {
      var params = {
        UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,
        AttributesToGet: ['given_name']
      };

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        AWS.config.update({
          region: USER_POOL_REGION,
          accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
          secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY
        });
        var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
        cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(data);
            setUsers(data)
          }
        });
      });
    };
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  return users.map(user => {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>{user.given_name}</li>
      </ul>
};

export default ListUsers;
```

One thing that I have noticed is that it doesn't seem to be setting state. Pretty sure that is because I'm doing it wrong. What I need to do is be able to map over the data that is returned as it is doing in the return statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it does not seem like creating your own Promise was necessary, your hook will work just fine without it :

```
  useEffect(() => {

    var params = {
      UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,
      AttributesToGet: ['given_name']
    };

    AWS.config.update({
      region: USER_POOL_REGION,
      accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY
    });

    var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        setUsers(data)
      }
    });

  }, []);
```

But the main problem seems to be coming from the JSX you return, as it cannot be an array of nodes.

In your case, you should return a `ul` tag and `map` your users within it like the following (don't forget to give them a unique `key`) :

```
  return (
    <ul>
      {users.map(user => <li key={user.given_name}>{user.given_name}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
```